# При компиляции .py в .exe 32-bit на 64-bit системе я могу его запустить на windows 10 64-bit, а на windows 7 32-bit не могу, почему?

Tags: python, exe, auto-py-to-exe

Есть скрипт .py который я скомпилировал на 3.12 32-bit версии питона при помощи библиотеки auto-py-to-exe, для windows 7 32-bit.

У меня стоит 64-bit система и 32-bit .exe-шник у меня запускается, а на 32-bit системах нет. При запуске на 7 windows 32-bit выдаёт сообщение от несовместимости.

Пожалуйста объясните как это работает и как можно решить проблему.

Comment: Покажите команду компиляции.

Comment: А точно 32-битный exe? Покажите ошибки, возникающие при запуске.

Comment: Возможно, та 32-х разрядная система очень старая (XP?). Используйте более старую версию python и auto-py-to-exe, совместимую с целевой ОС.

Comment: Да даже на Windows 7 Python 3.12 не работает. Для XP нужна версия Python 3.4, для Win7 - кажется 3.7. Дополните вопрос информацией об ОС.

Comment: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  "D:/Cod/practice/Python-Telebot/main.py" - @wchistow

Comment: Прямо сейчас не могу скинуть скрин - @insolor

Comment: Вы всегда можете править свои вопросы: для этого достаточно воспользоваться ссылкой [edit] под текстом вашего поста. Важную информацию лучше включать непосредственно в исходное сообщение.

Comment: Ошибки нужно прикладывать не скринами, а текстом.

Comment: Винда 7 32-bit верно @insolor

Comment: Я проверил, для Win7 нужна версия Python 3.8: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udlln.png. Берите 3.8.10, например, это последняя с собранными инсталляторами, насколько я вижу.

Comment: Спасибо за инфу @insolor ! Как проверю, отпишусь.

Comment: @insolor спасибо вам! Всё работает